# Numeric type with Room db

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am trying to implement Room library and i have `NUMERIC` data type in my `SQLite` database. I tried to use `Double` because the value could have decimal points, but I get the error `Migration didn't properly...`

```
 @ColumnInfo(name = "data")
 var data: Double = 0.toDouble(),
```

Error message:

```
data=Column{name='data', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
data=Column{name='data', type='NUMERIC', affinity='1', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
```

How to implement `NUMERIC` type in Room?